# mouse and keyboard are not working after changing the motherboard?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, troubleshooting, mouse

I am just changed the motherboard of my PC, My USB mouse and Keyboard (PS2) aren't recognised by my computer. IS this problem because of my new motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect another keyboard and check the BIOS settings
Otherwise re-check you motherboard connections/jumper but USB port are connected directly to your motherboard no? (if not try to change for one of the port directly attached to the motherboard)